# Protection against power lines

Tags: power

I was wondering if there was any protective systems in place for if a power line falls like one that would stop the electricity going to it but I can't find any. Does anyone know if there is and what its called?

Comment: Like a circuit breaker or earth fault detection relay?

Comment: yes like a earth fault detection relay i cant find any info on them can you link please? :))))

Comment: No, I would have to look it up, the same as you.

Comment: Remember, such breaker devices (in the US), are there to protect the expensive electrical infrastructure.  They are not there to protect _you_.  If the neighboring tree happens to not be zapped enough to light on fire, saving your house... well, that's just a happy secondary result.

Comment: I can't help myself.  I'd suggest this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6Ftv3zt-gI

Comment: Most transmission and sub transmission circuits have voltage and current monitoring through a device called a relay which allows for many different protection schemes e.g. earth fault, line differential, distance, over current, over/under voltage and frequency to name a few